# getText and setText function not working in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i tried to make my first converter in android studio with java but 2 functions setText and getText are not working

```
package com.example.unitconvertor;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity<editTextTextPersonName> extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private editTextTextPersonName editTextTextPersonName;
    private View editText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "value saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String s = editText.getText().toString();
                int inch = Integer.parseInt(s);
                double cm = 2.54 * inch;
                editText.setText( "the value is" + cm);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

i hope that i am clear
thankyou

Comment: What's not working?  WHat are you getting instead?

Comment: `private View editText;` – You need to declare that as an `EditText`, not a `View`; e.g., `private EditText editText;`. I'm not sure what's going on with the line above that.

Comment: You aren't actually setting the value of the editText variable anywhere either, so it would be null causing a crash, unless you just forgot to post that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private Button button;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.your_id);//ADD YOUR EDIT TEXT ID HERE


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "value saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String s = editText.getText().toString();
                int inch = Integer.parseInt(s);
                double cm = 2.54 * inch;
                editText.setText( "the value is" + cm);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that your "edittext" is declared as view, correct it like this : `private EditText edittext;`
then, retrieve it by id like this in your onCreate method `edittext = findViewById(R.id.your_id);`